# Most Efficient way to find the index of an item in a SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

I am using a sorted dictionary to maintain a list of items, of which I regularly need to monitor the state of the top x items. Every time I update an item, I'd like a quick way of figuring out what index the item I'm referring to is using. I understand I can enumerate the entire list and count out my position, but I am looking for something with O(log n) time or better, after all the sorted dictionary is on a RedBlack tree. Each node should be able to keep track of its children, and this should be a quick calculation.

Comment: Have you considered switching to a `SortedList<T>`? It can do `O(1)` retrieval by index. It does have awful performance on inserts and removes, though.

Comment: Since this is a tree structure, there is no concept of an Index. Just nodes with a left and right child link.

Comment: I don't understand this question - items in trees don't have an index.

Comment: @Lee that's the all point of the question . he is asking :
SINCE a tree does not contain an index how is .Net's SortedDictionary(Tree Based) be used in an O(log(n)) Range Query 
since in order to get to the "Index" you wan't you need to traverse the entire SortedDictionary and check from your range forward ,
you then result in an O(n) search which kinda contradicts the search part of the SortedDictionary .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply change your `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` into a `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` and then use `IndexOfKey(key)`:

```
var s = new SortedList<string, string>
    { { "a", "Ay" }, { "b", "Bee" }, { "c", "Cee" } };

// Outputs 1
Console.WriteLine(s.IndexOfKey("b"));
```

`IndexOfKey` internally uses `Array.BinarySearch<TKey>()`, so it will be O(log *n*), which is faster than O(*n*) (which it would be if you searched from front to back by iterating through it).

Comment: what if you needed a O(1) insert and Delete in addition to the O(log(n) search ?

Comment: @eranotzer: Then you will need to use a `Dictionary<K,V>` (you can’t have O(1) insert if it’s supposed to be always sorted) and you will need to manually sort it to do the O(log n) search (e.g. by using `dic.Keys.ToList()` followed by `Sort` and then `IndexOf`).

Comment: @Timwi it isn't `O(log n)` to do a search if you are using `.ToList()` you are making it `O(n)`... and if you are doing `.Sort()` average performance would be `O(n log n)` or at worst `O(n^2)`... Unfortunately you can never have `O(1)` insert into a BST unless its the first element.

Answer (score 1):

A tree structure could be constructed to access items by index or report the index of an existing item in lgN time, requiring very slight extra time for inserts and deletes.  One way to do this would be to keep track of how many items are in the left and right branches of each node (on an insert or delete, change the node count of parent nodes when changing the count of the children).  If a tree-based structure does not offer such a facility, though, I know of no easy way to retrofit it.

Comment: This is the angle I was looking for - but am looking for a structure that already has it, or an easy way to retrofit.